# Unity webgl, how to force fullscreen on mobile device

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, webgl

i have my game in webgl.
On tablet or laptop, i can succeed to set the game to fullscreen, but on mobile i cant.

On itch.io the succeed i don't know how to set to fullscreen by default: https://devdebabi.itch.io/flipflap

But when i deploy on my s3, i don't have the same result: https://gara-html-games-dev.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/masseka/12345/index.html

The code look like below. I don't really know how to proceed. I even try to use the fullscreen feature provided by the browser without success: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_fullscreen.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Unity WebGL Player | Flip flap</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="TemplateData/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="TemplateData/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="unity-container" class="unity-desktop">
      <canvas id="unity-canvas" width=800 height=600></canvas>
      <div id="unity-loading-bar">
        <div id="unity-logo"></div>
        <div id="unity-progress-bar-empty">
          <div id="unity-progress-bar-full"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="unity-warning"> </div>
      <div id="unity-footer">
        <div id="unity-webgl-logo"></div>
        <div id="unity-fullscreen-button"></div>
        <div id="unity-build-title">Flip flap</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      var container = document.querySelector("#unity-container");
      var canvas = document.querySelector("#unity-canvas");
      var loadingBar = document.querySelector("#unity-loading-bar");
      var progressBarFull = document.querySelector("#unity-progress-bar-full");
      var fullscreenButton = document.querySelector("#unity-fullscreen-button");
      var warningBanner = document.querySelector("#unity-warning");

      // Shows a temporary message banner/ribbon for a few seconds, or
      // a permanent error message on top of the canvas if type=='error'.
      // If type=='warning', a yellow highlight color is used.
      // Modify or remove this function to customize the visually presented
      // way that non-critical warnings and error messages are presented to the
      // user.
      function unityShowBanner(msg, type) {
        function updateBannerVisibility() {
          warningBanner.style.display = warningBanner.children.length ? 'block' : 'none';
        }
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = msg;
        warningBanner.appendChild(div);
        if (type == 'error') div.style = 'background: red; padding: 10px;';
        else {
          if (type == 'warning') div.style = 'background: yellow; padding: 10px;';
          setTimeout(function() {
            warningBanner.removeChild(div);
            updateBannerVisibility();
          }, 5000);
        }
        updateBannerVisibility();
      }

      var buildUrl = "Build";
      var loaderUrl = buildUrl + "/build.loader.js";
      var config = {
        dataUrl: buildUrl + "/build.data.gz",
        frameworkUrl: buildUrl + "/build.framework.js.gz",
        codeUrl: buildUrl + "/build.wasm.gz",
        streamingAssetsUrl: "StreamingAssets",
        companyName: "masseka",
        productName: "Flip flap",
        productVersion: "0.1.0",
        showBanner: unityShowBanner,
      };

      // By default Unity keeps WebGL canvas render target size matched with
      // the DOM size of the canvas element (scaled by window.devicePixelRatio)
      // Set this to false if you want to decouple this synchronization from
      // happening inside the engine, and you would instead like to size up
      // the canvas DOM size and WebGL render target sizes yourself.
      // config.matchWebGLToCanvasSize = false;

      if (/iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        // Mobile device style: fill the whole browser client area with the game canvas:

        var meta = document.createElement('meta');
        meta.name = 'viewport';
        meta.content = 'width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=yes';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
        container.className = "unity-mobile";
        canvas.className = "unity-mobile";

        // To lower canvas resolution on mobile devices to gain some
        // performance, uncomment the following line:
        // config.devicePixelRatio = 1;
      } else {
        // Desktop style: Render the game canvas in a window that can be maximized to fullscreen:

        canvas.style.width = "800px";
        canvas.style.height = "600px";
      }

      loadingBar.style.display = "block";

      var script = document.createElement("script");
      script.src = loaderUrl;
      script.onload = () => {
        createUnityInstance(canvas, config, (progress) => {
          progressBarFull.style.width = 100 * progress + "%";
        }).then((unityInstance) => {
          loadingBar.style.display = "none";
          fullscreenButton.onclick = () => {
            unityInstance.SetFullscreen(1);
          };
        }).catch((message) => {
          alert(message);
        });
      };
      document.body.appendChild(script);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the game  you linked did not force full screen for me, so this is not a good example.  They removed the ablity to force full screen you can only do it on keypress/buttonclick now. If you mean the "full screen" button on the web page, it works on my site too and i have done nothing special its more something wrong on yours

Comment: @BugFinder on mobile, the button is not displayed. Probably you tried on laptop. I want to know how to add this button  to activate the fullscreen using browser capability.

Comment: well if you read the code theres a section about "if (/iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) " making it full screen and if not putting it in a window.. so perhaps you need to start there,.  Your fullscreen button doesnt work on my laptop on your website however, suggesting it thinks it hasnt fully loaded somehow

Answer (score 0):

I is simple, on itch.io the game is opened in an iframe. So i did something similar.

First i put the screen in full screen then activate the iframe to load the game.
You can add a way to detect when the user exit fullscreen, to hide again the iframe.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Fullscreen with JavaScript</h2>
<p>Click on the button to open the video in fullscreen mode.</p>
<button onclick="openFullscreen();">Open Video in Fullscreen Mode</button>
<p><strong>Tip:</strong> Press the "Esc" key to exit full screen.</p>

<div style="height:100%" id="myvideo">
 <iframe id="html5game"  style="display:none; width: 100%; height: 100%; border:0; " src="https://gara-html-games-dev.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/masseka/12345/index.html" title="description"></iframe> 
</div>


<script>
var elem = document.getElementById("myvideo");
   
function openFullscreen() {
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
    document.getElementById("html5game").style.display='block';
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Safari */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
     document.getElementById("html5game").style.display='block';
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
    document.getElementById("html5game").style.display='block';
  }
}
</script>


<style>
#html5game {
   display:none;
}
</style>

<p>Note: Internet Explorer 10 and earlier versions do not support the msRequestFullscreen() method.</p>

</body>
</html>
```